# What is the FPS drop in this game loop?

Tags: java, class, rendering

Can someone tell my why the FPS keeps dropping from 100 (desired) to 91 every few iterations? I made everything as concise as I could from my original application, where I used double buffering and active rendering, in this example the same thing happens but I use passive rendering. The FPS constantly drops form 100 to 91 and I can't figure out why!

Code

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class Test extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    Image img;

    int fps;
    @Override 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        }

    }

    public void gameUpdate() {

}

public void gameRender() {
Graphics g  = getGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

}


    public void startGame()  {
        if(thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    private Thread thread;
    @Override
    public void run() {
    long beforeTime = 0;
    long afterTime = 0;
    long timeDiff = 0;
    int period = 10000000;
    long sleepTime = 0; 
    long overSleepTime = 0;
        while(true) {
            beforeTime = System.nanoTime();
            gameUpdate();
            gameRender();
            repaint();
            afterTime = System.nanoTime();
            timeDiff = afterTime - beforeTime;
            sleepTime = (period - timeDiff) - overSleepTime;

            if(sleepTime > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime/1000000L);
            }  catch (InterruptedException e){}
            long threadSleepTime = System.nanoTime() - afterTime;
            overSleepTime  = threadSleepTime - sleepTime;

            fps = (int)FPSCounter.getFPS(threadSleepTime, timeDiff);
            System.out.println(fps);
        } // end if

        } 

    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        startGame();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Title");
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(new Test());
        f.setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

Separate class

```
/**
 * Return the current FPS
 * @param threadSleep Amount of time thread has slept
 * @param renderTime Amount of time took rendering/updating
 * @return
 */
public static double getFPS(long threadSleep, long renderTime) {
    return 1000000000 / (threadSleep + renderTime);
}
```

Comment: Also please don't edit the title and misspell FPS as FDS.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code to see where it slows down?

Comment: Also, don't use `getGraphics` to perform custom painting, this will be wiped clean the next time that the repaint manager decides to paint your component and, because you're doing it from a thread, could produce dirty paints

Comment: ^ Yeah I understand. I just made this up to demonstrate my problem quicker. I use getGraphics on the image with active rendering. I haven't tried profiling but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: You never reset `overSleepTime` if `sleepTime <= 0`...

Comment: Try to achieve a higher FPS, like 140, or so, and see if your computer is capable of doing that. If not, then, you will see the maximum.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Nice catch, but I think that that would only increase the FPS, instead of decreasing.

Comment: I do reset overSleepTime (in my good application)... Like I said I just whipped this up to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: Well, it stopped the output for me, twice in a row...

Comment: here is the output: 91
101
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
91
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
101100
100
100
92
112
100
101
100
101
100
91

Comment: Could it be caused by the gc?

Comment: I think trying to check every 10 milliseconds for the frame rate might be been a little optimistic, as thats only really taking into account that individual cycle, rather then taking into account the fact that the algorithim can over or under speed based on individual cycles.  A more accurate result might be to average out the number of cycles you were able to complete in a given second...

Comment: @BitNinja The OP's not operating in the context of the EDT ;)

Comment: Another issue is the fact that `repaint` will return immediately after scheduling a paint event onto the event queue, this means you're not actually seeing a true representation of the frame rate, just saying ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know repaint() is not accurate and it cannot be relied on for accurate measurements. Also I apologize if I seemed rude to you before and in my previous questions. You certainly deserve more respect since you've been doing Java related work since 2000. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @user254886 No offense taken, I know what it's like when you're trying to get an answer to your problems and silly people keep poking holes in areas that aren't immediately an issue to you ;)